# Facebook not Respecting preferredTransform flag on AVMutableCompositionTrack

Tags: objective-c, facebook, rotation, cgaffinetransform, avmutablecomposition

I have an AVMutableComposition track which I am rotating 180 degrees as follows :

```
if (shouldRotate) {

    //Code to rotate original main video 180 degrees if required.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    a_compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = transform;

}
```

This works well and when I view the video or upload to YouTube it is correctly rotated. However when I upload to Facebook the video is upside down - it seems that Facebook does not care about / read the preferredTransform flag.

Can anyone suggest how I might fix this ? Just for extra information I am using the Facebook  SDK for iOS to upload the videos.

Thank you in advance !

EDIT Actually this seems to be a bug either on Facebook or in the Facebook sdk. If I rotate by 90 degrees it works. If anyone can shed any light please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug - the only solution is to rotate the video once uploaded in Facebook itself.